# Prove by induction that $n^2 \gt 3(n + 1) , ∀ n\ge 4 $

Tags: inequality, induction

First I showed the base case for n=4:

$ 4^2 \gt 3(4+1) \iff 16 \gt 15 \\ $ which is true

Let n=m

Now we need to show that $ m^2 \gt 3(m+1) \implies (m+1)^2 \gt 3(m+1+1)$

$ m^2 \gt 3(m+1) \iff m^2 + 2m + 1\gt 3(m+1) + 2m +1 \iff (m+1)^2 \gt 5m + 4$

This where I got stuck. My textbook follows this with $5m + 4 \gt 3m+6 $ and then

$(m + 1)^2 > 5m + 4 > 3m + 6 ⇒ (m + 1)^2 > 3m + 6 = 3(m + 2)$

The part I don't understand is how they just say that $5m + 4 \gt 3m+6 $

How can they just say that? Is it because it holds true for $m=4$?

Comment: Note that $5m+4>3m+6$ is equivalent to $m>1$.

Comment: You can prove that claim inductively if you want to. I think the book assumed it was trivial/didn't need to be proven.

Comment: Because they need $3m+6$ in the right hand side, not $5m+4.$

Comment: @Bumblebee I understand why it's there, I just don't understand why they can just say it without showing.

Comment: @GitGud right, that makes sense and in hindsight it should have been pretty obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see that you need to have $3(m+2)$ at the right hand side, but at some point you end up with $5m+4$. So can you prove $5m+4 > 3m+6$? If yes, you're done, if not come back and double check your steps. In this case it is trivial that $5m+4 > 3m+6$ because this is equivalent to $2m-2 > 0$, which gives $m > 1$. Your $m$ is definitely greater than $4$, hence the first inequality holds and you can conclude.